# postfix - users are geting mail from them self that they did not send

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp, email-server

Our company has a mail server configured with postfix/dovecot/amavisd on Ubintu 14.04. The system has been running for a couple of years and it worked fine. Recently some users started complaining that they got some mail from themselves, that they did not send. The server is not an open relay.
I tried to enable authentification, but then no other mail could be recived.

My question is, if it is posible in any way to reject/deny mail that was not send from our users in our domain?

postfix main.cf:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mxserver.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.mxserver.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unlisted_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings

# DKIM
# --------------------------------------
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Postfix master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d vmail ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop} ${sender}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - - - - smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
        -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks,no_milters
```

Comment: "they got some mail from themselves, that they did not send" it would be useful if you add maillog and headers for such email

Answer (score 1):

Add an spf record for your domain at DNS level. You can create your spf record from online spf wizards. It is a txt record and should look like this

```
example.com.  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a -all"
```

Then configure your server to check spf.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF

Answer (score 1):

You can use [smtpd_restriction_classes](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_restriction_classes)

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_restriction_classes = restricted_sender
restricted_sender = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
 check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_domain
 reject_non_fqdn_sender
```

Add all you domains to the list

```
# cat /etc/postfix/restricted_domain
example.com restricted_sender
example.net restricted_sender

# postmap /etc/postfix/restricted_domain

# postconf mynetworks
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
```

Some basic tests

**Sender within mynetworks. No authentication - Access granted**

```
# echo "Hello world" | swaks -4 --server localhost --from alex@example.net --to alex@example.net --h-Subject "Test message" --body -
=== Trying localhost:25...
=== Connected to localhost.
<-  220 smtp.example.net ESMTP Postfix
 -> EHLO jenkins.example.net
<-  250-smtp.example.net
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> MAIL FROM:<alex@example.net>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<alex@example.net>
<-  250 2.1.5 Ok
 -> DATA
<-  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 -> Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 10:12:47 +0000
 -> To: alex@example.net
 -> From: alex@example.net
 -> Subject: Test message
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20130209.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 ->
 -> Hello world
 ->
 ->
 -> .
<-  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 327251C1566
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
```

**Sender outside mynetworks. No authentication - Access denied**

```
# echo "Hello world" | swaks -4 --server smtp.example.net --from alex@example.net --to alex@example.net --h-Subject "Test message" --body -
=== Trying 192.168.88.87:25...
=== Connected to 192.168.88.87.
<-  220 smtp.example.net ESMTP Postfix
 -> EHLO tl-resin-node1.example.net
<-  250-smtp.example.net
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> MAIL FROM:<alex@example.net>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<alex@example.net>
<** 554 5.7.1 <alex@example.net>: Sender address rejected: Access denied
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
```

**Sender outside mynetworks. With authentication - Access granted**

```
# echo "Hello world" | swaks -4 --server smtp.example.net --auth PLAIN --auth-user alex@example.net --auth-password 1234567 --from alex@example.net --to alex@example.net --h-Subject "Test message" --body -
=== Trying 192.168.88.87:25...
=== Connected to 192.168.88.87.
<-  220 smtp.example.net ESMTP Postfix
 -> EHLO tl-resin-node1.example.net
<-  250-smtp.example.net
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> AUTH PLAIN [HASH]
<-  235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
 -> MAIL FROM:<alex@example.net>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<alex@example.net>
<-  250 2.1.5 Ok
 -> DATA
<-  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 -> Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 06:20:10 -0400
 -> To: alex@example.net
 -> From: alex@example.net
 -> Subject: Test message
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20130209.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 ->
 -> Hello world
 ->
 ->
 -> .
<-  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D04581C7EAD
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
```