# Postfix SMTP authentication security hole

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have Postfix running on CentOS 6. Everything is working ok except for a security hole in the smtp.

I keep getting spam emails sent from my address to my address. I have checked this out on telnet, and the server allows me to send emails to myself without authentication. If I try to send to an external email address, then the authentication is required.

How can I plug this hole??

**EDIT:**

@Jenny D This is not a duplicate of the question. I want to prevent my mail server from sending emails to itself without authentication.

#### postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = mail/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = mydomain.com
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination       $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps  $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains  $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps  $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,       permit_mynetworks, check_relay_domains,  reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-     virtual_forwardings.cf,         mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

#### grep -n smtp /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
11:smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
13:587      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
15:#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
16:#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
17:smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
18:   -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
19:   -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender=yes
20:   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated
22:#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
24:#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
25:#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
26:#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
27:#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
43:smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
45:relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
46: -o smtp_fallback_relay=
47:#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
102:#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
103:#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
```

#### Headers

```
Return-Path: <nadiam1pa@mydomain.com>
Delivered-To: myaddress@mydomain.com
Received: from [103.38.130.142] (unknown [103.38.130.142])
by 807493.myserver.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6A8894809B6
for <myaddress@mydomain.com>; Mon, 28 Mar 2016 14:22:52 +0100 (BST)
From: "netadmin" <nadiam1pa@mydomain.com>
To: "myaddress@mydomain.com" <myaddress@mydomain.com>
Subject: Document (1).pdf
Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 18:52:55 +0530
Message-ID: <087e40a2476d5abe1036e9eda4563@mydomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0042_01D0A1F9.171F24B0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
Thread-Index: AdCh6FNHn/LWax1JSTSc7XL2c2t2TQ==
Content-Language: en-US

This is a multipart message in MIME format.
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT 2:**

I have added reject to end of smtp_sender_restrictions - this fixed my problem, however it also broke incoming mail??

To illustrate the problem more clearly - I want the following to be rejected, but it is not:

```
Connected to mail.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 807493.vps-10.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo testing.com
250-807493.vps-10.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from:myaddress@mydomain.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:myaddress@mydomain.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
```

If I change to:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain,    
 permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

Then I get the desired result:

```
Connected to mail.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 807493.vps-10.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo testing.com
250-807493.vps-10.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from:myaddress@mydomain.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:myaddress@mydomain.com
554 5.7.1 <myaddress@mydomain.com>: Sender address rejected: Access denied
```

However incoming emails from exterior addresses are now bouncing and being received!

Sorry, but I am finding this very difficult to understand.

Comment: You can use smtpd_restriction_classes - http://serverfault.com/questions/766060

Comment: Thanks @Alex_hha. I tried this and just causes the server to hang? Not sure that this would solve the problem for sending mail from myaddress@domain.com to itself anyway?

Comment: With such settings only authenticated users or hosts from mynetworks can send mail from your domain to your domain

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't get this working. The server just hangs after EHLO. I am using a mysql database for user credentials and postfix 2.6.6 - if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set sender ID verification in your mail server...receiving mail from your own ID is spoofing mails which can be stopped by settings sender ID and configuring SPF records in your DNS server..

Comment: Thanks, but can you point me towards a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: i have followed following steps for my exchange server please try to search same thing for the POSTFIX. http://www.windeveloper.com/imftune/tutor/vid9_ex13_antispam_part4.htm

Answer (score 0):

Postfix seems to use `permit_auth_destination` in one of its [access restriction lists](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists).

I couldn't figure an exact cause of the issue. Please, could you add in the question:

1. The output of `postconf -n`?
2. The output of `grep -n smtp /etc/postfix/master.cf`?
3. Headers extracted from a spam mail?

---

**EDIT:**

I see that the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` setting contains a `reject_unauth_destination` and no other additional restrictions. Also, neither `defer` nor `reject` restriction is applied, so an implicit `permit` prevails.

Let me write how your Postfix daemon behaves when it receives a `RCPT TO` command in a SMTP transaction. Consider that a remote client started it and intends to send a fake message from and to `myaddress@mydomain.com`.

1. `permit_sasl_authenticated` => User didn't authenticate, so this restriction is ignored.
2. `permit_mynetworks` => User doesn't belong to the internal network, so this restriction is ignored.
3. `check_relay_domains` => Postfix seems to have deprecated this restriction, so it may also be ignored.
4. `reject_unauth_destination` => Postfix detects that it is the final destination of the message, so the restriction is ignored.
5. An implicit `permit` takes place, so Postfix finally accepts and delivers the message.

You can add a `reject` or a `defer` restriction at the end of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` if you intend to receive messages from authenticated users only. However, if you are going to receive messages from domains that you don't own (i.e. a public mail server), you have to follow other alternatives, as an explicit `reject` or `defer` will reject those messages. Apply the resolution pointed by @Jenny D, that is, either set `check_sender_access` restriction or configure [Sender Policy Framework](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF).

Also, you can apply additional anti-spam techniques:

- Add `reject_unknown_client_hostname` restriction.
- Enable RBL checking against the [Spamhaus Block List](https://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/) ([example](https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-fight-spam-with-postfix-rbl/)).
- Configure [greylisting](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postgrey).

Comment: Thanks, I have added the requested info to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Anderson M. Gomes, that is very helpful and almost worked- but my problem is still not fully resolved. Please see EDIT 2!

Comment: Well, I did write that a `reject` or a `defer` restriction could be added if the mail server was planned to receive messages from authenticated users only. Please, check [Postfix SMTP relay and access control](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) document to figure the logic behind Postfix restrictions. The supported ones are documented along the [postconf (5)](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) man page.

Comment: Note that SMTP is a protocol designed in a distant past, when Internet was a safe environment and all e-mails were desirable. The behavior that you call _a security hole_ is actually by design. If you post a message to a mailing list, for example, the external server may send an e-mail whose sender and recipient addresses are yours. SMTP itself isn't designed to reject such messages; you have to either configure SPF, [restriction classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html) or [sender access maps](http://serverfault.com/a/444413/293407). Solutions have already been pointed.